# escape a character vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i need to post from VB.NET to a php server 
so i have this code witch is doing the post method to the php file
the function works prefectly
but when i put "&" character it's making some problems

```
function SendProsser(ByVal txt, ByVal type)
        Dim postData As String
        Dim msg as string  = "fine&good"

            postData = "msg=" & msg 


        Dim tempCookies As New CookieContainer
        Dim encoding As New UTF8Encoding
        Dim byteData As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(postData)

        Dim postReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/msg.php"), HttpWebRequest)
        postReq.Method = "POST"
        postReq.KeepAlive = True
        postReq.CookieContainer = tempCookies
        postReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        postReq.Referer = "http://localhost/x7/filemanager.php"
        postReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/4.0 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
        postReq.ContentLength = byteData.Length

        Dim postreqstream As Stream = postReq.GetRequestStream()
        postreqstream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
        postreqstream.Close()
        Dim postresponse As HttpWebResponse

        postresponse = DirectCast(postReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        tempCookies.Add(postresponse.Cookies)
        logincookie = tempCookies
        Dim postreqreader As New StreamReader(postresponse.GetResponseStream())
        ' Dim thepage As String = postreqreader.ReadToEnd


    End Function
```

Comment: The contentType you're setting should give you a hint: "x-www-form-**URLENCODED**"

Comment: `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(postData)` before conversion to the byte array

Comment: wont work, thanks tho

Comment: *wont work*? Why not?

Comment: Just need to URLEncode the msg portions so it would be  `postData = "msg=" & System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(msg)`